# Why does TweetSharp always return only 100 followers?

Tags: c#, twitter, tweetsharp

I'm using the [TweetSharp](https://github.com/danielcrenna/tweetsharp) library in a .NET 4 (C#) application.

Here is a helper method I built that returns followers for a given user.

```
public static void FindFollowersForUser(TwitterUserModel twitterUser)
{
                                            //A simple string for screen name.
    var followers = service.ListFollowersOf(twitterUser.TwitterName);
    foreach (var follower in followers)
    {
                   //Followers is a simple List<string>.
        twitterUser.Followers.Add(follower.ScreenName);
    }
}
```

The code runs fine but using breakpoints I see that even if the user has more than 100 followers (I check on the official site), the object in my application has only 100.

Is there a way to get all of the followers for a twitter user using TweetSharp?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to go through the cursor:

```
var followers = service.ListFollowersOf(twitterUser.TwitterName, -1);
while (followers.NextCursor != null)
{
    followers =  service.ListFollowersOf(user_id, followers.NextCursor);
    foreach (var follower in followers)
    {
         twitterUser.Followers.Add(follower.ScreenName);
    }
}
```

You can see this in some of the tests: https://github.com/danielcrenna/tweetsharp/blob/master/src/net40/TweetSharp.Next.Tests/Service/TwitterServiceTests.cs

Comment: Thanks, it never occurred to me to search through the unit tests.

Comment: +1 for reminding folks about the "living documentation" that are unit tests.

Comment: Just a warning: the rate limiting is pretty aggressive. If you start getting `null` from those calls then inspect `service.Response` to see if it's rate limiting causing the issue.