# How to retrieve all Twitter users with TweetSharp using cursors?

Tags: c#, .net, twitter, cursor, tweetsharp

I'm using TweetSharp in a WPF .NET 4.0 C# app and using an authenticated Twitter service object. **I'm having issues iterating through a list of followers to retrieve every single profile.** I'm using the following code:

```
TwitterCursorList<TwitterUser> followers = twitterService.ListFollowersOf(userID, -1);
while (followers != null)
{
    foreach (TwitterUser follower in followers)
    {
        //Do something with the user profile here
    }
    followers = twitterService.ListFollowersOf(userID, (long)followers.NextCursor);
}
```

I see a weird behavior when I use this against my own account, which has 1271 followers as of this writing. The 1st time I run the code, I get a list of 100 followers, and on the next ListFollowersOf call, followers is null and the loop ends.

**Here is the weird part**: If I run this code again, whether in the same app instance, or if I stop Visual Studio and restart, doesn't matter, I get one extra ieration and now I get 200 followers back. If I do this trick again, now I get 300 followers back before I get a null, and so on. I repeated this many times until one call of the code above returned all 1271 followers.

The really weird thing is this eventually resets. I think it's tied to the Twitter API limit reset time, but I have not verified that. I'll see if this coincides with the API reset. Once the reset happens, I only get 100 followers, then 200, and so on.

I have reviewed TweetSharp unit tests and the following posts and they did not work for me:

- [How to get the complete list of followers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8743551/how-to-get-the-complete-list-of-followers)
- [Why does TweetSharp always return only 100 followers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10694566/why-does-tweetsharp-always-return-only-100-followers)

Comment: Did you try `while (followers.NextCursor != null)`? Your while loop stops when `followers` is `null`, yet the other examples in the questions you linked stop when the `NextCursor` is `null`.

Comment: I have. followers.NextCursor returns a long?, and the issue was that once followers became null (and it does, as explained above), I would get an null reference exception thrown.

Comment: One of the [tests provided with the source](https://github.com/danielcrenna/tweetsharp/blob/master/src/net40/TweetSharp.Next.Tests/Service/TwitterServiceTests.cs) checks if `NextCursor` is `null` and you're casting it to long, so it does seem like it's a reference of some sort (I don't have the code to check it). Here is the check: `Assert.IsNotNull(followers.NextCursor);` You can still check if `followrs` is `null` and don't reference it if it's `null`, but it looks like your while loop should keep going until `NextCursor` is `null`... at least that's how it looks from the other examples.

Comment: I initially tried not casting to long but VS was throwing a compiler error "cannot convert from 'long?' to 'long'". I also get another compiler error "The best overloaded method match for 'TweetSharp.TwitterService.ListFollowersOf(int, long)' has some invalid arguments".

Comment: If `NextCursor` can be checked for `null` it's either a reference type or it's a nullable value type. Value types, like `long`, cannot be `null` unless the field/property/variable is declared as a nullable (e.g. `long?`). If the method expects a `long` you have to cast `NextCursor` to `long` regardless if it's a reference type or a nullable `long?`.

Comment: I checked every single overload and all cursor parameters expect a long, NOT a nullable long?, so I guess my cast is required. I don't understand how prior examples in these other threads ever worked. It could be an older version of TweetSharp that allowed that. Regardless, the mystery remains: Why would the method return a null after 100 followers, and then 100 more if I run the SAME code again.

Comment: Check my answer... I think that your code should look like that based on the examples I've seen. I don't have the library, so I can't run the code, but try it and let me know if it works.

Answer (score 1):

I use something like this:

```
public static List<TwitterUser> GetFollowers(this TwitterService svc)
{
    List<TwitterUser> ret = new List<TwitterUser>();

    var followers = svc.ListFollowers(-1);
    ret.AddRange(followers);
    while (followers.NextCursor != null && followers.NextCursor.Value > 0)
    {
        followers = svc.ListFollowers(followers.NextCursor.Value);
        ret.AddRange(followers);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

and then

```
var f = svc.GetFollowers();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the library, but based on the examples it looks like you should have something like this:

```
TwitterCursorList<TwitterUser> followers = twitterService.ListFollowersOf(userID, -1);
while (followers.NextCursor != null)
{
    if(followers != null)
    {
        foreach (TwitterUser follower in followers)
        {
            //Do something with the user profile here
        }
    }
    followers = twitterService.ListFollowersOf(userID, (long)followers.NextCursor);
}
```

Again, I can't run the code since I don't have the library (too lazy to download it too), but give it a shot and let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting anything back it's because your code works just fine.

It's easy to find out what's going wrong and then begin to fix your problems accordingly. I suspect that you're correct and that you are being rate-limited by Twitter.

Add this to your code after your while-loop:

```
if(followers == null) {
    Console.WriteLine("Error " + twitterService.Response.Error);
}
```

In fact, any time something returns `null` you can check the Response object's Error to see what it is TweetSharp thinks went wrong. [See this](https://github.com/danielcrenna/tweetsharp#handling-errors).